# Transforming values passing between two SQL DBs in Node project

Tags: javascript, sql

In my Node project I am querying one SQL database and am then, as necessary, transforming the data, and then writing it to another SQL database. In order to handle situations where I needed to write a string value to the receiving database, but the value might be null (and I didn't want to write "null" to the db), I handled it this way:

```
const sqlStringOrNull = function (value) {
  return value ? "'" + value + "'" : null;
};
```

That worked fine for first few situations where the sending db used 'varchars'. But now I have a situation where the db being queried has `char(9)` values. And, as far as I can tell, even if the value itself is, say, 4 characters long, the remaining characters will be passed on as empty spaces. So with my current implementation, while I don't get errors, when I console log my query being passed, I see values like this: `'1234     '`.

My question is, first of all, is this what's happening? Will a `char(9)` value in SQL Server, always have 9 characters, even if the actual value is fewer than that?

And, if so, how I can amend my function to trim values when that's the case? What I tried was this:

```
const sqlStringOrNull = function (value) {
  if (value) {
    value = "'" + value + "'";
    return value.trim();
  } else if (!value) {
    return null;
  }
};
```

This didn't give me any errors, but it also didn't seem to trim the values as expected. What am I missing here? How can I handle the data so that, when it's a string, it ends up being trimmed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, columns with `CHAR` datatype will always return fixed length data, padding any short values with empty space.

As for your second code block, you should call `.trim()` before adding the single quotes, e.g.:

```
const sqlStringOrNull = function (value) {
  if (value) {
    return "'" + (value.trim ? value.trim() : value) + "'";
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

Comment: I end up with a `value.trim() is not a function` error when I run records through this. I wonder if I also need to be sure by checking that typeof === 'string'?

Comment: Yes, I assumed all of your values were strings. Code edited to cope with other datatypes.

Comment: Tried your updated code. Still got the same error. I tried this and got a different error: `const sqlStringOrNull = function (value) {
  if (value && (typeof value === 'string')) {
    return value.trim();
  } else if (value && (typeof value !== 'string')) {
    return "'" + value + "'";
  } else if (!value) {
    return null;
  }
};`